# TYPO3 FLUID blank page TYPO3

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

I try to create my first FLUIDTEMPLATE. But the Methode

> f:layout

dont get activated.

My structure:

```
/fileadmin/
/fileadmin/layouts/layout.html
/fileadmin/partials/
/fileadmin/styles/
/fileadmin/templates/template.html
/fileadmin/typoscript/
/fileadmin/typoscript/01_script/setup.ts
/fileadmin/typoscript/02_object/
```

setup.ts:

```
page = PAGE
page.typeNum = 0

page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {
    format = html
    file = fileadmin/templates/layouts/layout.html
    partialRootPath = fileadmin/templates/partials/
    layoutRootPath = fileadmin/templates/layouts/
    variables {
        content_main < styles.content.get
        content_main.select.where = colPos = 0
    }
}
page.10.file.stdWrap.cObject = CASE
page.10.file.stdWrap.cObject {
    key.data = levelfield:-1, backend_layout_next_level, slide
    key.override.field = backend_layout

    default = TEXT
    default.value = fileadmin/templates/template.html
}
```

Layout.html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
      <div id="header">
      header
      </div>

      <div id="top_nav">
      top_nav
      </div>

      <div id="left">
      left
      </div>      

      <div id="right">
      right
      </div>

      <div id="center">
          center
      </div>

      <div id="footer">
       footer
      </div>
</div>
```

template.html:

```
<f:layout name = "Layout" />
```

template setup:

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source ="DIR:fileadmin/typoscript/">
```

Now, if i view the webpage i only see a blank page. If i look on the code i get that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- 
        This website is powered by TYPO3 - inspiring people to share!
        TYPO3 is a free open source Content Management Framework initially created by Kasper Skaarhoj and licensed under GNU/GPL.
        TYPO3 is copyright 1998-2017 of Kasper Skaarhoj. Extensions are copyright of their respective owners.
        Information and contribution at https://typo3.org/
    -->



    <title>Fluid</title>
    <meta name="generator" content="TYPO3 CMS">


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="typo3temp/Assets/b9db200ac9.css?1491821607" media="all">

    </head>
    <body>
    <f:layout name = "Layout" />

    </body>
    </html>
```

I am using TYPO3 v7.6.16.

Comment: <f:layouts... > is a typo? (no pun intended)
AFAIK in fluid you should use files that begins with capital letter

Comment: But it dont change nothing.

Comment: Here is the step by step guid http://thomas.deuling.org/2011/06/create-a-complete-typo3-website-by-using-the-fluid-template-engine/. Hope this will help you!

Comment: i already try it it dont help me!

Comment: in your typoscript you should use *Paths instead of *Path, also you should define templateRootPaths.0 and furthermore use only templateName instead of file.

Comment: I am not sure if i do it right. But it dont work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Templates:** Startseite.html

```
<f:layout name="Default" />

<f:section name="body">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            {header->f:format.raw()}
        </div>

        <div id="top_nav">
            {top_nav->f:format.raw()}
        </div>

       <div id="left">
            {left->f:format.raw()}
       </div>      

       <div id="right">
            {right->f:format.raw()}
       </div>

       <div id="center">
            {center->f:format.raw()}
       </div>

       <div id="footer">
            {footer->f:format.raw()}
       </div>
   </div>
</f:section>
```

you can configure same for inner page(Inhaltsseite) layout.

**Layouts:** Default.html

```
<f:render section="body" />
```

**Typoscript:** (setup.ts)

```
lib.pageTemplate = FLUIDTEMPLATE
lib.pageTemplate {

    templateName = TEXT
    templateName.stdWrap.cObject = CASE
    templateName.stdWrap.cObject { 
        key.field = backend_layout

        # @todo: setup all page templates
        default = TEXT
        default.value = Startseite

        1 = TEXT
        1.value = Inhaltsseite

    }

    templateRootPaths {
        10 = fileadmin/templates/Resources/Private/Templates/
    }    
    partialRootPaths {
        10 = fileadmin/templates/Resources/Private/Partials/
    }
    layoutRootPaths {
        10 = fileadmin/templates/Resources/Private/Layouts/
    }

    variables {
        content = CONTENT
        content {
            table = tt_content
            select.orderBy = sorting
            slide = -1
            select.where = colPos=0
        }
    }
}

# Page setup Configuration
page = PAGE
page {
    # Your TypeNum
    typeNum = 0

    #Include header data if any
    headerData{
    }

    #Include website meta
    meta{
    }

    #Include stylesheet
    includeCSS {
    }

    #Include Js files(In the header)
    includeJS {
    }

    #Include Js in footer
    includeJSFooter {
    }

    # assign template (copy fluid template object)
    10 < lib.pageTemplate
}
```

Include setup.ts in the template->include->setup.ts from the BE.

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT:source="FILE:fileadmin/templates/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.ts" />
```

Greetings!

Comment: how to Include setup.ts ? it will show up as a item?

Comment: @thenewOne1234567890, Use <INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT:source="FILE:fileadmin/templates//Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt" /> to include file.

Comment: why it is a setup.txt? And can you show me the structure of you project because i am now little bit confused.

Comment: @thenewOne1234567890, Oops! sorry dear, i right code in the txt file thats why i included txt file, you can include your setup.ts instead of setup.txt file extension work works file.

Comment: I get this error : The page is not configured! [type=0][]. This means that there is no TypoScript object of type PAGE with typeNum=0 configured.

Comment: This because you have to configure your fluid template inside PAGE object. Now you can create an page object in your typoscript setup and copy lib.pageTemplate inside object. Let me update answer.

Comment: this works. i dont knowe realy why but you did it! THX

Comment: Welcome @thenewOne1234567890, for more details you can visit http://thomas.deuling.org/2011/06/create-a-complete-typo3-website-by-using-the-fluid-template-engine/. will give you step wise details.. Have fun :)

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your example code. Lets go through them:

1. You should not put your templates in the fileadmin where they are (by default) accessable by web requests and editable by editors. Instead put them inside an extension under `Resources/Private/`.
2. You should not specify the layout file as your template. You have

   file = fileadmin/templates/layouts/layout.html

Instead of the layout.html you should point to a template like your Template.html inside `Resources/Private/Templates`

3. In your template you then may include a layout file. But remove the whitespaces: `<f:layout name="Layout" />`.
4. Use UpperCase names for your template, layout and partial files (`Template.html` instead of `template.html`).
5. Use `templateRootPaths` and `layourRootPaths` and `partialRootpaths` instead.

So your TypoScript could look like this:

```
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {
    format = html
    file = EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Templates/Template.html
    partialRootPaths {
        10 = EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Partials/
    }
    layoutRootPaths {
        10 = EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Layouts/
    }
    templateRootPaths
        10 = EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Templates/
    }
    variables {
        content_main < styles.content.get
        content_main.select.where = colPos = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: To 1. Create file Resources/Private/ and out it into - > typo3conf->ext To 5. ok i change setup.ts. But how can i say to my template where the ts is. Because its hiden?

Comment: I am sorry, I dont understand your question. Can you try to rephrase?

Comment: You first point (1) = > I create a the file Resources and Private. And put them into -> typo3conf->ext. Is this correct ? To you fifth point (5). I take you code and put it into setup.ts (look my structure). Now i need to tell the template in typro3 where that setup.ts is. So i write into a new created tampled this  -> <INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source ="DIR:fileadmin/typoscript/">

Comment: Service Unavailable (503)

The page is not configured! [type=0][]. This means that there is no TypoScript object of type PAGE with typeNum=0 configured.

Comment: I have a very basic example on github, that uses a fluidtemplate from an extension. The purpose of the example is to show how gulp can be integrated in TYPO3 but you can see the structure I was describing in my answer there as well: https://github.com/ervaude/gulp_example

Comment: In the TypoScript template in the backend there would be the line `<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source ="EXT:gulp_example:Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt">`

Comment: I change it completely like you say and it still don t work: structure like yours on githup. - typo3conf/ext/Configuration/TypoScript with setup.ts - typo3conf/ext/Resources/Private/Layouts with Layout.html -typo3conf/ext/Resources/Private/Partials -typo3conf/ext/Resources/Private/Templates with Templates.html  In the TypoScript template: <INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source ="EXT:typo3conf:Configuration/TypoScript/setup.ts"> i also change my_ext to ext in setup.ts. I Get this Error: 
The page is not configured! [type=0][]. This means that there is no TypoScript object of type PAGE with typeNum=0 co..

Answer (score 0):

you first have to create a page object in typoscript (which is missing in the typoscript above):
page = PAGE
this should be the first line in your typoscript.